# if, for, or while with an empty body, use empty braces instead of a semi-colon

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Using [google closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/error-ref) I get the following warning message:

```
WARNING - If this if/for/while really shouldnt have a body, use {}.
```

Here's what the documentation says:

> This warning means that you have a semi-colon immediately following an
>   if, for, or while statement. For example:
>
> ```
> // Produces JSC_SUSPICIOUS_SEMICOLON warning:
> if (true);
> else alert('no');
> ```

Is this just a code convention thing or is `{}` better than `;` for some reason?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just test for the opposite?

Comment: @Mathletics what do you mean?

Comment: It's more clear to me that the if/for/while has an empty body if I read {}

Comment: Why wouldn't you write `if (!condition) alert('no')` instead of the empty body?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This guards against things like:

```
if(condition);
{
    // oops, I really meant for this to be conditional.
    // now it always executes, regardless of condition.
}
```

The error raised forces you to explicitly put the empty `{}` before the `;` so it's clear that that's what you intended.

Comment: Java permits such of this mistakes, now i understand why this "feature" is harmfull and must be used with huge caution.